Modify a model based upon a users value?
I need to have a component that has a text input, but what the user types is modified before sending it up to the parent model...
const model = defineModel({
    type: String,
});

const inputModel = ref('');

<input v-model="inputModel" />

So I declare model using defineModel so the parent can access it.
I also declare inputModel so my inputs value is stored soemwhere.
But, how do I modify the inputModel and assign it to model?
For example, let's pretend we want to use .toLowerCase():
const model = defineModel({
    type: String,
});

const inputModel = ref('');

<input v-model="inputModel" /> //when this changes set model.toLowerCase() - how?


Do you want to keep both values? or you just need the lowercased input value?

@huanfeng just modify the value that the user sees, yet keep the dat value unchanged.

it seems the question has been answered in another question posted by you
